# How would I make 2 divs float next to each other but not have the content underneath follow suit?

Tags: html, css, css-float

[image]

I have this setup, with HTML:

```
<h4 class="wrap-title">Name</h4>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs title-button" ng-click="uploadNewImage()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload</button>    
                    <p>{{venue.name}}</p>
```

and CSS:

```
.wrap-title {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.title-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  float:none;
}
```

How would I go about having the Creams be underneath "Name"? Thanks in advance! I can't for the life of me figure out how for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a little cleaner to wrap the floats in a div and use a the clearfix

```
<div class="clearfix">
   <h4 class="wrap-title">Name</h4>
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs title-button" ng-click="uploadNewImage()">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
    </button>    
</div>
<p>{{venue.name}}</p>
```

here the clearfix css

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }

.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
```

Here is the explanation given in the html5 boilerplate

Clearfix: contain floats For modern browsers

1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
   Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
   that receive the `clearfix` class.
2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
   `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask how the content/display properties achieves this?

Comment: I've added the explanation from html5 boilerplate to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the float:

```
p {
clear:left:
}
```